# determining the fermi velocity via density of states

Tags: integration, physics, mathematical-physics

The problem is to determine the Fermi velocity for a fermion gas at absolute zero. the problem using integrating a function that looks like

$$ v = \frac{4\pi V}{h^{3}} m^{3} \int_{0}^{\infty}{ \frac{v_{f}^{3} \, dv}{e^{\frac{\frac{mv_{f}^{2}}{2} - \mu}{kt}} + 1} } $$

which is supposed to equal $ \frac{3 v_{f}}{4}$. It also mentions something about integrating by parts.
Does anyone know how to integrate that?

Thank you.

Comment: The *indefinite* integral involves the polylogarithm function, so for the definite integral to have a simple form, some sort of asymptotic is required. Here is an idea: add and subtract a function which looks just like yours but without the $+1$. Such a function is easy to integrate by parts. Then try to play with the "error term".

Comment: No, this would be too much calculation for an MSE answer, my assistance will be limited to hints. Sorry. Also, you should clean up your notation: you are using $v$ both as a variable on the outside and as a variable of integration. You should avoid doing this, and instead use a dummy variable ($u$, perhaps) in the integral. As it stands your original equation is clear enough, but somehow you are saying $v=\frac{3v}{4}$, which doesn't make sense in context.

Comment: i tried it and it still isn't working @Ian

Comment: Now your notation is still wrong: I think you want $v_f$ on the left side and $v$ inside the integral, or something like that.